# Calendar return wrong current date android

Tags: java, android, calendar

Why does this code return 0001-02-05?

```
public static String getNowDate() throws ParseException
{        
    return Myformat(toFormattedDateString(Calendar.getInstance()));
}
```

I changed the code to:

```
public static String getNowDate() throws ParseException
{        
    Calendar temp=Calendar.getInstance();
    return temp.YEAR+"-"+temp.MONTH+"-"+temp.DAY_OF_MONTH;
}
```

And now it returns 1-2-5.

Please, help me get the actual date. all i need is the Sdk date.

Comment: Thanks! But Alex, already help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

You are using constants to be used with the `Calendar.get()` method.

Comment: Nope, it appears I'm not Jon Skeet ;-)

Comment: Loooong way to go :) Thanks however, I'll take it as is ;)

Answer (score 16):

`Calendar.YEAR`, `Calendar.MONTH`, `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` are `int` constants (just look up in the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html))...

So, as @Alex posted, to create a formatted `String` out of a `Calendar` instance, you should use SimpleDateFormat.

If however you need the numeric representations of specific fields, use the `get(int)` function:

```
int year = temp.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = temp.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int dayOfMonth = temp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

**WARNING!** Month starts from 0!!! I've made some mistakes because of this!

Comment: +1 for the warning. The dumbest part about this is that Calendar.MONTH starts at zero but DatePickerDialog's input for month of the year does not. Make up your mind android /:

Comment: This comment was solution for my broblem - "WARNING! Month starts from 0!!! I've made some mistakes because of this!"
Why do the made this so funny, month starting from 0 to 11, not from 1..12))

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `SimpleDateFormat`?

```
public static String getNowDate() {
  return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Change to:

```
return temp.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+ (temp.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) +"-"+temp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Also, you may want to look into [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

```
Date dt = new Date();
//this will get current date and time, guaranteed to nearest millisecond
System.out.println(dt.toString());
//you can format it as follows in your required format
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(dt));
```

Comment: These are ugly. SimpleDateFormat is exactly doing what OP needs... And Date.toString() is not to be relied upon!

Comment: Wow, really? The OP wanted to fix his code. I gave him his fix. And I added a note that he may want to look into Date. You're suggesting SimpleDateFormat, but you're completely misunderstanding there. SimpleDateFormat does not give you the date-time NOW, it only formats a given date-time. So where are you suggesting to get the date-time NOW from? `Date` or `Calendar`? And you -1 my answer for this? Unbelievable...

Comment: `Date` is guaranteed to the nearest millisecond when getting the date-time NOW and it's better than `Calendar`. There's nothing unreliable about it as far as practical purposes go. Also to note, I just updated the answer to show that I won't rely on `Date.toString()` at all when I need a formatted date as the OP did. I use the original `Date` object.